# Why this flux isn't executed in multiple threads?

Tags: java, reactor

I have the following example:

```
Flux.just(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
    .flatMap(integer -> {
                 System.out.println("val:" + integer + ", thread:" + Thread.currentThread().getId()); 
                 return Mono.just(integer);
             }, 5)
    .repeat()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())
    .subscribe();
```

logs are as follows:

```
val:4, thread:14
val:5, thread:14
val:6, thread:14
val:7, thread:14
val:8, thread:14
val:1, thread:14
val:2, thread:14
val:3, thread:14
```

why the same thread everywhere?? How can i modify the example so it is executed in multiple threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want each repeated flux to be on a different thread, you can move the `publishOn` before, like this:

```java
Flux.just(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
        .publishOn(Schedulers.parallel()) // <- before
        .flatMap(integer -> {
           System.out.println("val:" + integer + ", thread:" + Thread.currentThread().getId()); 
           return Mono.just(integer);
        }, 5)
        .repeat()
        .subscribe();
```

The output is like that now:

```
val:1, thread:20
val:2, thread:20
val:3, thread:20
val:4, thread:20
val:5, thread:20
val:6, thread:20
val:7, thread:20
val:8, thread:20
val:1, thread:13
val:2, thread:13
val:3, thread:13
val:4, thread:13
val:5, thread:13
val:6, thread:13
val:7, thread:13
val:8, thread:13
```

If you want each integer to be in a different thread, you can do something like this:

```java
Flux.just(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
        .publishOn(Schedulers.parallel()) // <- Each flux can be published in a different thread
        .flatMap(integer -> {
            return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
                 System.out.println("val:" + integer + ", thread:" + Thread.currentThread().getId()); 
                 return integer;
            }).publishOn(Schedulers.parallel()); // <- Each Mono processing every integer can be processed in a different thread
         })
        .repeat()
        .subscribe();
```

The output becomes:

```
val:3, thread:16
val:2, thread:15
val:7, thread:20
val:8, thread:13
val:5, thread:18
val:6, thread:19
val:3, thread:17
val:5, thread:19
val:6, thread:20
val:1, thread:15
val:8, thread:14
val:4, thread:18
val:7, thread:13
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `parallel` operation as below :

```
Flux.just(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
    .parallel(2) // mention number of threads
    .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
    .map(integer -> {
             System.out.println("val:" + integer + ", thread:" + Thread.currentThread().getId()); 
             return integer;
        })   
    .subscribe();
```